# How to create users having different access privileges?

Tags: user-management

I want to create 3 users. First user have only the read only permission, that is this user can read all file but can not write, delete and edit file?

The second user is execute only user can not see any file from machine but he can fire all file command like copy,edit etc.

The last user only concern about terminal window,he login through terminal like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> window after that he can't see desktop screen, only terminal window like ms-dos system (No graphical user interface only terminal).

Comment: Users will r,w & x on the same folder/file? If not answer is yes.

Comment: I do not see any sense behind doing this. User one with read-only permission souns ok, but why should somebody be able to execute files he can not see (if even possible)? And I am not sure if you can disable any desktop environment to an user and force him to use a tty either. Maybe you could inform us about your aim, what you want to achieve finally?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for so here goes something.

Since you want 3 users with unique permission, I think you will have 4 users on your system
1st Root (frank), 2nd, 3rd, and 4th for unique user permission.

Create three seperate groups for each user (group1, group2, group3). Do this via root user.

Now simply change ownership of files via chown

```
chown -R rootusername:groupname ### /path/to/folder/file
```

so if your root username is frank, you are setting permission for user1 to set read and write only

```
chown -R frank:group1 740 /path/to/folder/file
```

Hopefully this helps you get on the path you were looking for.

Comment: chown -R rootusername:groupname ### /path/to/folder/file not working.. it gives error like ###(740) not a directory or path